# How do I check if a message DOES NOT start with the prefix?

Tags: discord, discord.js

Title mostly says it all, how do I check if a message doesn't start with the prefix so I can send a message alerting the user they didn't use the prefix?

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```js
const prefix = '!' // or whatever yours is

//inside message listener

if (!message.content.startsWith(prefix) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer is similar to Gh0st's answer but he had a syntax error in his code

```js
const prefix = "!" //or whatever you want
//your msg listener will be here
if(!message.content.startsWith(prefix)) {
   //do stuff here
}
```

Comment: Fixed that error, thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if (!message.content.startsWith("prefix") return; // "prefix" as your prefix
```

This checks if the message's content starts with the prefix you put in. If it doesn't, it will ignore the message.